# How do I make my first purchase of cryptocurrency?

Tags: buy-bitcoins

I'd like to get started in cryptocurrency.  Be it Bitcoin, Dogecoin or something else.

I'd like to keep my own wallet and not use a Coinbase type of service.

How do I start?  Who would I send money to?  And how do I know what I get is of real value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download and install Bitcoin Core: https://bitcoin.org/en/bitcoin-core/
2. Create a wallet and receiving address there (it's better to use encryption when creating wallet).
3. Buy bitcoin on any available BTC exchange (Coinbase, Binance, etc.).

> I'd like to keep my own wallet and not use a Coinbase type of service.

You can keep your wallet on your own, but to buy BTC, you will need to use service or find a person who wants to sell you ones.